# Pulse width reader printing same value every time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm connecting my raspberry pi to a 2.4ghz rc reciever, and I am trying to use python to interpret the pulse width signal. I am using an input pin to read the time while there is no input, then the time when there is an input, then subtracting the two.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(15,GPIO.HIGH)

start = time.time()
stop = time.time()

x = 0
y = 0

while(x == 0):
    if(GPIO.input(13) == 0):
        start = time.time()
        x = 1

while(y == 0):
    if(GPIO.input(13) == 1):
        stop = time.time()
        y = 1

Width = stop-start

print(Width)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

The issue I am having is that no matter how long I make the pulse width (by manually connecting and disconnecting pin 13 and 15), it prints ~.006. It also will not print until I disconnect the pins from each other, although I haven't been able to figure out why.

Comment: Can't see why that wouldn't work, but you may be better of with interrupts instead: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=43069

Answer (score 0):

Pin 13 might be floating. I'd suggest you replace ...

```
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.IN)
```

... with ...

```
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
```

Here's an example of how to do this with interrupts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# example of reading PWM with GPIO interrupts
# Warning: Linux isn't built for real-time applications.
# A Raspberry Pi with Jessie will not produce reliable results
# That said...

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIOpin_IN = 13
GPIOpin3v3 = 1 # fixed at 3v3 volts
myStart = None
myStop = None

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(GPIOpin_IN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def pinGoesUp(gpioIdentity):
    myStart = time.time()

def pinGoesDown(gpioIdentity):
    myStop = time.time()

GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIOpin_IN, GPIO.RISING, callback=pinGoesUp)
GPIO.add_event_detect(GPIOpin_IN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=pinGoesDown)

while True:
    if myStop < myStart:
        Width = stop-start
        print(Width)`
```

[documentation on gpio input](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/).

On a side note, you're going to have difficulty getting reliable readings. Jessie is not intended to provide real-time interaction, and frequently takes small vacations to do other tasks.